# MATLAB: .mat file opens in 1x1 structure

Tags: matlab, file, structure, mat

Okay so I have a structure:

```
    sub_info(1)= struct('Name',info_array{1},'Number',info_array{2},
'Date',info_array{3}, 'Student_ID', info_array{4});

    mat_struct = 'matstruct.mat'
    save(mat_struct, 'sub_info')
```

But when I try to open the .mat file. It opens as a 1x1 struct. Is there a way to load it in mat format?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure what's wrong? You saved the struct sub_info in a file 'matstruct.mat' and when you execute `load matstruct.mat` it will load the struct `sub_info` you saved back into memory. What's the problem?

Comment: I want it to be saved in a .mat file format. But for some reason its showing up as 1x1 struct in the workspace. How do I make it show up as .mat?

Comment: look in your local directory. There should be a file called "matstruct.mat" that your code generated. There is your .mat file. I don't know what you mean with, "How do I make it show up as .mat?" or "Is there a way to load it in mat format? "

Comment: No I see it there, but i want it to open in a mat format too. When I open it, it looks more like a structure than a normal mat file

Comment: What action do you want to take? And what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: Since `sub_info` is a struct, when you load it you will have a struct. I'm not sure what else you could expect?

Comment: @David My guess is he wants to examine the contents of the .mat file by double clicking the .mat file (like you would open a word document). Of course, double clicking a .mat file tells Matlab to LOAD the file into the workspace (or brings up a dialogue box to that effect), which is not what he's expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define a simple struct variable

```
sub_info(1)= struct('Name','aaa','Number','bbb');
```

and save it to a file:

```
save('file', 'sub_info')
```

There are **two ways** of using [`load`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html):

- **Without output arguments**: `load file`, or `load('file')`.

  This produces the original variable `sub_info` in the workspace:

  ```
  >> load file
  >> whos
    Name          Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
    sub_info      1x1               260  struct
  >> sub_info
  sub_info = 
        Name: 'aaa'
      Number: 'bbb'
  ```
- **With an output argument**: `x = load('file')`. This produces a struct **whose fields are the variables contained in the file** (so in this case `x` has a single field `sub_info`):

  ```
  >> x = load('file');
  >> whos
    Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
    x         1x1               384  struct              
  >> x
  x = 
      sub_info: [1x1 struct]
  >> x.sub_info
  ans = 
        Name: 'aaa'
      Number: 'bbb'
  ```